# How to create a char[] using data from a boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `Boolean` array and I am trying to make a corresponding char array, so that to each true in the new array corresponds a 1 and for each false a 0. this is my code but it seems the new array is empty, because nothing prints, the `Boolean nums[]` prints fine.

```
char[] digits = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (nums[i]) {
        digits[i] = 1;
    }
    else if (!nums[i]) {
        digits[i] = 0;
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    System.out.print (digits[k]);
}
```

Comment: First comment your else does not need if since if current index value is not true it will always be false

Comment: Also, there's no need to use `nums[i] == true`, just use `nums[i]`, since that's a boolean itself

Comment: Also you could use conditional if directly
`digits[i]= nums[i] ? 1 : 0` and completely dump your if else blocks

Comment: What's the value of `n`? Can you show us the contents of `digits`?

Comment: @Youans: I wouldn't go for the ternary operator yet, he's clearly a beginner so it's better to start with more readabale code imo.

Comment: the value of n is user input. digits should contain only zeroes and ones, but it does not print anything, nus prints trues and falses fine though

Comment: My mistake, I meant `nums`.

Comment: ok, I changed the else if with just else and now it prints some weird symbols where the ones should be and spaces for the zeroes. It changes when I try to paste it so it may be useless but still 13

Comment: nums contains true for the prime numbers and false for the non prime, up to n, for n==13
truetruetruefalsetruefalsetruefalsefalsefalsetruefalsetrue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have quotes surrounding the `1` and `0`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (nums[i]) {
        digits[i] = '1';
    }
    else {
        digits[i] = '0';
    }
}
```

Without the quotes, they are cast from `int`s to `char`s. 0 is actually the null character (`NUL`), and 1 is start of heading or something like that. Java chars are encoded using UTF-16 (they're 16 bits long). The characters '0' and '1' are actually encoded by 48 and 49 respectively (in decimal).

EDIT: Actually, don't look at the ASCII table, look at the [Unicode character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Unicode is really a superset of ASCII, but it'll probably be more useful than the ascii table

Answer (score 4):

According to [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in the *Language Basics* lesson of trail *Learning the Java Language* in Oracle's Java tutorials:

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Unicode value 0 (zero) is a non-printing character, as is unicode value 1 (one). That's why you aren't seeing anything printed. Either change `digits` to a `int` array or fill it with character literals such as `'0'` or `'1'`

If you use `int` array, the following code will suffice:

```java
int[] digits = new int[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (nums[i]) {
        digits[i] = 1;
    }
}

for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {
    System.out.print (digits[k]);
}
```

Note that a `int` array is implicitly initialized such that all the elements are initially 0 (zero).

Answer (score 3):

You can convert like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        boolean[] nums = { true, false, true, false, true };
        char[] digits = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            digits[i] = nums[i] ? '1' : '0';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like that

```
char[] myChars = new char[n/16];
for(int i=0;i<nums.length/16;i++);{
  String myChar ="";
  for(int j=0;j<16;j++){
     if(nums[i*16+j])
        myChar+="1";
     else
        myChar+="0";
  }
 myChars[i]=Integer.parseInt(myChar,2);
 }
```